# How to implement Rounded Corner Effect in a List

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I have successfully implemented Rounded Corner ListView inside CustomAdapter class, like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);
        viewHolder.textTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);

        if (position == 0 && arrayList.size() == 1) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.top_list_selector);
        }
        else if (position == 0) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.top_list_selector);
        }
        else if (position == arrayList.size() - 1) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_list_selector);
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mid_list_selector);
        }

        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
```

But I don't know How can I implement same in below class, I do understand that in place of `arrayList` I have to use `countryList` but what about `view` and `position` ?

```
public class CountryFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_social, container, false);

        displayListView();

        return view;
        }

    private void displayListView() {

        //Array list of countries
        List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
        countryList.add("Country 1");
        countryList.add("Country 2");
        countryList.add("Country 3");
        countryList.add("Country 4");
        countryList.add("Country 5");

        //create an ArrayAdapter from the String Array
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.adapter_social, countryList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listCountry);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                switch( position )
                {
                    case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Country 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                        .....
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using array adapter , you must use custom adapter class otherwise you can not achieve this .

Comment: @UmeshChhabra thanks i have implemented it using Custom Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 1 code example, the use created a custom adapter to display alist of items, something like

```
MyCustomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

Where as in your code you simply displayed already build in adapter, which do not support to `Override` `getView()` method in which all this changes can be made.

So, in order to do what the example is doing, create a class

```
static class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {    


        private List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

        public void addView(View view){
            views.add(view);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return views.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return views.get(position).getTag();
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return views.get(position).getId();
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return views.get(position);
        }
    }
```

And instead of doing

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.adapter_social, countryList);
```

Do

MyListAdapter listAdapter = new MyListAdapter();

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();  

        int item_layout = 0 ;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < values.length;i++) {

            //decide which layout to show depending on the item position
            if(i==0) {
                item_layout = R.layout.top_list_layout ;
            } else if(i==values.length-1) {
                item_layout = R.layout.bottom_list_layout;
            } else {
                item_layout = R.layout.mid_list_layout;
            }


            TextView button = (TextView)inflater.inflate(item_layout, null); 

            button.setText(values[i]);
            button.setTag(new Integer(i));

            listAdapter.addView(button);
        }




        //lv.setSelector(R.color.transparent);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```